# MomentJs invalid date from datepicker

Tags: reactjs, momentjs

I Am trying to format a date from [react datepicker](https://github.com/quri/react-bootstrap-datetimepicker), the value going in is `1441062000000`

```
onChangeStartDate: function(value) {
    this.setState({
        startDate: moment(value)
    })
},
```

When I check the date in dev tools I get a moment invalid date, can anyone tell me how I can create a date from the value?

I'm using the value `1443135600000` with format, but still getting invalid date:

```
onChangeEndDate: function onChangeEndDate(value) {
    console.log(moment(value, ConfigProvider.getKey('dateFormat')));
```

Answer (score 0):

You might need to pass the format as a second argument to `moment` - in case of react date picker, it defaults to `'x'`, e.g. unix timestamp:

```
this.setState({
    startDate: moment(value, 'x')
})
```

If you omit the second argument, moment tries to parse the input by [looking for ISO 8601 formats](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/), but a unix timestamp will cause this algorithm to fail. That's why you need to specify the format explicitly.

The other way would be to configure your date picker to emit changes in an IS 8601 compliant format, for example `format='YYYY-MM-DD'`.

Comment: Of course, `x` is only necessary if the input is a string.  If it's already a JS number, the it's not needed.

Comment: Could it be the value from the datepicker which is wrong?